# Help me debug this - C++ Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I am noob to C++ Boost. Can anyone here help me to debug this program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem; 
using namespace std;

void show_files( const path & directory, bool recurse_into_subdirs = true )
{
  if( exists( directory ) )
  {
    directory_iterator end ;
    for( directory_iterator iter(directory) ; iter != end ; ++iter )
      if ( is_directory( *iter ) )
      {
        cout << iter->native_directory_string() << " (directory)\n" ;
        if( recurse_into_subdirs ) show_files(*iter) ;
      }
      else 
        cout << iter->native_file_string() << " (file)\n" ;
  }
}

int main()
{
    show_files( "." ) ;
}
```

Wen I am trying to run this program I am getting error like

```
ex2.cpp: In function ‘void show_files(const boost::filesystem2::path&, bool)’:
ex2.cpp:15: error: ‘class boost::filesystem2::basic_directory_entry<boost::filesystem2::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem2::path_traits> >’ has no member named ‘native_directory_string’
ex2.cpp:19: error: ‘class boost::filesystem2::basic_directory_entry<boost::filesystem2::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem2::path_traits> >’ has no member named ‘native_file_string’
```

Tanx in advance. P.S. This program will list out all files/folders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two changes you need to make to get this working properly.  First of all, the iterator returns an instance of `basic_directory_entry`, not a path.  So first you need to query the `path` from the iterator.  Also, newer versions of boost have dropped the `native_` prefix from the accessor methods.

Here's your code with the changes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem; 
using namespace std;

void show_files( const path & directory, bool recurse_into_subdirs = true )
{
  if( exists( directory ) )
  {
    directory_iterator end ;
    for( directory_iterator iter(directory) ; iter != end ; ++iter )
    if ( is_directory( *iter ) )
    {
      cout << iter->path().directory_string() << " (directory)\n" ;
      if( recurse_into_subdirs ) show_files(*iter) ;
    }
    else 
      cout << iter->path().file_string() << " (file)\n" ;
  }
}

int main()
{
    show_files( "." ) ;
}
```

Comment: I tried above code. But its giving lots of error. BTW tanx for ur response

Comment: This compiles and runs perfectly on my machine (OS X with Boost 1.44).  The only changes from your code I detailed above. What are the errors you are getting?  The issue may be caused by the change from v2 to v3 in the Boost filesystem API, which makes a large number of interface changes.  If you tell me the version you are using, I'm sure we can work it out.

Comment: That is a linker error, not a compiler error. If you look at the undefined symbols, they're all in the `boost::system` namespace. This is because the `boost::filesystem` library has a dependency on `system`, so you just need to add `-lboost_system` to your linker flags.

Answer (score 4):

Since I can't simply add a comment to the (currently) top answer, I would like to make note of

boost::filesystem::wpath::native_file_string() being deprecated and changed to boost::filesystem::wpath::string().  So the following line

```
cout << iter->native_file_string() << " (file)\n" ;
```

becomes

```
cout << iter->string() << " (file)\n" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick peek at the documentation and I can't find any mention of `native_directory_string` or `native_file_string` against basic_directory_entry. AFAICT, these member functions belong to a different class (`filesystem::path`), which I think you can access from `basic_directory_entry` thus:

```
iter->path().native_directory_string()
```